# How can I refer to the row that the update is currently updating?

Tags: sql, oracle

TABLES:

- student(name,points)
- playsin(name->student(name), score)

I'm trying to use:

```
UPDATE STUDENT
   SET points = points + CONSTANT * (SELECT score 
                                       FROM PLAYSIN 
                                      WHERE playsin.name = student.name);
```

Comment: Could you please re-write it a little bit and make it more understandable?

Comment: @Filip: The algorithm reads to me as multiplying the student's score by a constant before adding to the existing students' point value.

Comment: This assumes that "name" can be used as a primary key, right?

Comment: @IronGoofy: Safe bet if it's a foreign key in the PLAYSIN table.

Comment: @rexem, just as i thought then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE STUDENT s
   SET points = s.points + CONSTANT * (SELECT p.score 
                                        FROM PLAYSIN p 
                                       WHERE p.name = s.name)
```

Table aliases are a very good habit to have.

Comment: Can't try it out right now, but is the alias really required? It seems that the references are clear even without the aliases.

Comment: @IronGoofy: I can't test either :/ But it's either the fact of referencing the points value in the equation to update it, or the join to the PLAYSIN table I figure.

Comment: Thanks, using aliases solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try updating an in-line view:

```
UPDATE (select s.name student_name,
               s.points student_points,
               p.score  playsin_score
          from STUDENT s,
               PLAYSIN p
         where p.name = s.name)
SET    student_points = student_points + CONSTANT * playsin_score;
```

It also limits the rows in STUDENT that are updated to only the set for which there
is a row in PLAYSIN (you might also consider in your current code what happens to SCORE if that subquery could return NULL). You'd need a unique or primary key on playsin.name to use this syntax to avoid a join cardinality check error, but if this is not feasible then a MERGE statement might be useful. A MERGE might be worth considering anyway if you also have code to add into STUDENT any new names in PLAYSIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this next :

```
UPDATE student s, playsin p
SET s.points = s.points + CONSTANT * p.score
WHERE p.name=s.name
```